Show compared strings in Diff2HtmlUI when there is no difference
I'm comparing two json objects then rendering them with Diff2Html
First I'm gnerating a diff string using Diff libbary
const diffString = diff.createTwoFilesPatch('file', 'file', this.reference, this.result, undefined, undefined, {
  context: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
});

When the two compared string are equivalent I'm getting an empty string , exactly :
"Index: file\n===================================================================\n--- file\n+++ file\n"

I render the string:
const div: HTMLElement = this.diffDiv.nativeElement;
const diff2htmlUi = new Diff2HtmlUI(div, diffString, this.configuration);
diff2htmlUi.draw();

Then Diff2Html renders this screen:

I would like that the same all of the string object get rendered. I don't find a way to do it

I had the same problem and found out that there is no way to do this (see github issue)
so instead I used their custom templates functionality
and changed the template that shows file without changes component to have the whole string in it
